# Azure Web App - Deploying Manually through ssh terminal

Tags: node.js, azure, ssh, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I've recently deployed a NodeJs Azure Web App and using Git to trigger the deployments when I make changes to the source code. Out of curiosity I was exploring the file system of the Linux server that's running the app and found the script file that's used for deployment (deploy.sh).

Is it possible to run that script file locally on the server while in an ssh session? For example if I wanted to make a change directly on the server to a file, instead of having to push the changes up through git (probably not a good idea but I want to know if it's possible regardless).

I tried running the script whilst in the directory where it's located but it failed to find the kudu sync command, which I thought was strange.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can run the deploy.sh file. If i am not wrong then you might be getting some error like --- can not be sub directory of each other. In this case you can try to run the deplo.sh from inside the wwwroot folder. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it still errors, the console logs the following error:

"Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../deployments/tools/../artifacts/manifest'"

Comment: its because its not getting its artifacts .. the location of deploy.sh is /home/site/deployments/tools>deploy.sh .. you can run the the command from bash on this path.

Comment: Tried that, still received the same error unfortunately.